# Has this algebraic structure been named or studied?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, formal-languages

Apologies if this is is not very well-defined or exposes my ignorance; I know comparatively little about abstract algebra.

The structure of certain programming languages can be described with the algebraic structure $(S,\cdot,\verb|^|)$ where

- $\cdot:S\times S\rightarrow S$  is associative and unital, and
- $\verb|^| : S \rightarrow S$

i.e., a monoid with an extra unary operation.  Unfortunately, nothing much can be said about $\verb|^|$ except that:

- $\verb|^|$ distributes over $\cdot$, i.e., $\verb|^|(a\cdot b) = \verb|^|a\cdot \verb|^|b$.
- $\verb|^|$ is cancellative: $\verb|^|a = \verb|^|$b implies $a = b$.

In particular, $\verb|^|$ is not an inverse operation, nor idempotent; in general, $\verb|^|(\verb|^|a) \neq a$, and in particular, $\verb|^|1\neq1$.

My question is:

> Has this structure been studied, or at least been given a name, in abstract algebra?

I'm not optimistic, because adding $\verb|^|$ doesn't appear to make the structure much more interesting than a monoid.  But if anyone can even point me towards similar structures, I'd be grateful.  (Although clearly groups are not a good fit because of the lack of invertibility.)

(**Edited** to include the cancellative property of $\verb|^|$ and to explicitly mention its non-idempotency.)

---

A concrete example of the structure is: strings of symbols with brackets, with a semantics which gives the substrings inside brackets a different meaning. Joy is one such programming language based on this framework. The underlying monoid for Joy is well-described in [that paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20111107025958/http://www.latrobe.edu.au/phimvt/joy/j02maf.html), but the bracketing operator (Joy's [...], my ^) is much less well-described algebraically, and I'm trying to find out more about where it might fit in (or be made to fit in.)

Comment: So basically what you're describing is a monoid with an endomorphism on it, right?!

Comment: Does $\land a=\land b$ imply $a=b$?

Comment: Also, is it known at least that ^1=1? If not, then @ineff is wrong that ^ is an endomorphism.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to see specific examples that you are trying to formalize, so that we might have some idea whether there are additional commonalities other than the ones you have listed.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, ^a=^b implies a=b.  But no, ^1≠1.  I take it that, if ^1=1 held, it would be an endomorphism?    Thanks to you and ineff for pointing this out -- it may be possible to reformulate things (in a contrived way) to get a special restricted case where ^1=1 and see where that leads me.

Comment: Yes, if $\verb|^|1=1$ then $\verb|^|$ is an endomorphism. The cancellation rule eliminates the examples I thought of immediately, such as closure operators on subsets of a topology (with intersection being the binary operator.) Definitely, you should add the cancellation rule ($\verb|^|a=\verb|^|b\implies a=b$) to your question.

Comment: @Thomas: a concrete example of the structure is: strings of symbols with brackets, with a semantics which gives the substrings inside brackets a different meaning.  [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/phimvt/joy/j02maf.html) is one such programming language based on this framework.  The underlying monoid for Joy is well-described in that paper, but the bracketing operator (Joy's [...], my ^) is much less well-described algebraically, and I'm trying to find out more about where it might fit in (or be made to fit in.)

Comment: Unfortunately, cancellation takes it out of the realm of universal algebra, I think, which generally makes studying an algebraic structure harder.

Comment: @Thomas, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll vote it up.  Even knowing that it's not an endomorphism is helpful.  In a sense, ^ imposes a hierarchical structure on the elements of S, which I think suggests that I should look into things like lattices instead.

Comment: Nobody has used the word "monomorphism" as far as I can see. Why not? Isn't that what ^ is?

Comment: In general, the semantics of programming languages are much more complicated than what can be captured at this level... You may want to read about [algebraic semantics of PLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_semantics_(computer_science)), but it's not the most popular approach to PL semantics, as I recall... Wikipedia only managed a couple of sentences in a "stub"... but there are a couple of useful references on that page.

Comment: You also have to distinguish between the syntactic monoid in which the programs are
written and the semantic monoid which interprets those as functions with composition (that much is explained in the link you gave). It's not clear about which one you're asking here... Monoids of functions actually have additional properties (especially if the functions are total.) To quote Wikipedia "The set of all partial functions (partial transformations) on a given base set, X, forms a regular semigroup ". Not sure if Joy has typing so if you need to consider categories (instead of monoids).

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup is a specific structure; that sentence I quoted doesn't mean it's "just any semigroup".

Comment: In wikipedia's page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup we also find a useful link in that regard wrt to programming https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~mauro/pubs/Notions_of_Computation_as_Monoids_ext.pdf

Comment: Why is everyone talking about "cancellation" and "cancellative" when the word "injective" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it is not necessarily true that $\verb|^|1\neq 1$, we can't even say that $\verb|^|$ is an endomorphism of the monoid (only an endomorphism of the semigroup.)

The cancellation rule for $\verb|^|$ makes this hard to study in category theory. Without the cancellation rule, this would be some sort of "universal algebra." With the cancellation rule, we have a harder problem. (We don't talk about the category of integral domains, but really only the category of rings in general. The same is true here.)

By the way, it is not at all obvious that the "quote" operator of Joy distributes as you say. It seems like the description of "quote" in that article does not make $[ab]=[a][b]$. It depends on what it means, I guess, to "push onto the stack," but as I take it, $[a][b]$ pushes two things onto the stack, while $[ab]$ pushes only one.

Comment: True, Joy's quote does not work like that, but it's fairly easy to make a variation which does, and I was hoping that adding another property (however slight) might bring it closer to something algebraically conventional.  Joy's quote is also intensional, whereas what I'm working with is extensional.  I just realized that that means, in Joy, a=b does _not_ imply [a]=[b]; but [a]=[b] still does imply a=b, and at any rate, extensionality is pretty important for my current purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this one can meet you requirement:

Let $(S,+,\centerdot)$ be a semiring,  and treat your $\centerdot$ as $+$,  treat your ^a as $a\centerdot c$ for a fixed $c$.

Even though it has more properties than your structure, it's the best one I can think of.

Comment: The commutativity of + is not a good fit, but the idea of fixing a _c_ like that is intriguing.  Do you happen to know if there's a good example of using that technique in some other context?

Comment: How about this one: near-semiring, which does not require the commutativity, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring. For example the addition and multiplication of ordinals form a near-semiring, if you define your ^a as $c\centerdot a$ (it only has right distributive law), then the structure has all the properties you list, without invertibility,idempotency and commutativity

Comment: That would work better, assuming I can find a suitable $c$.  It is possible to transform programs in these languages in a way that removes brackets and adds a symbol which basically says "bracket this other thing"; that operator is a good candidate for this $c$.  But there are issues with associativity that I don't know if I can get around, with that approach; it'll take some time for me to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the structure is a pair of a monoid (though not a unital) and a monomorphism $(S,\verb|^|)$. A morphism $S\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} S^\prime$ should be a (non unital) monoid morphism $\alpha$ such that the diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    S @>\alpha>> S^\prime\\
    @V \verb|^| V V{\#} @VV \verb|^| V\\
    S @>>\alpha> S^\prime
    \end{CD}

But I don't know anything about that structure, not its name or history.